# Minimal number of defining relators of a finite $p$-group on a minimal generating set

Tags: gr.group-theory

What is the state-of-art of the following question?

Let $p$ be any prime number. For any finite $p$-group $G$, let $r_G$ denote the minimum number of defining relators in all presentations of $G$ over  minimal generating sets of $G$.Let $R_G$ denote the dimension of the second cohomology group of $G$ mod $p$.

Question: Is there a finite $p$-group $G$ such that $r_G > R_G$?

Has it been checked for all $2$-groups of order at most $2^{10}$ or other small $p$-groups which we know them by the small group library of GAP?

Is a possible example studied to have certain properties? e.g. must it be  of nilpotency class at least $3$?