# A possible presentation with 2 generators and 2 relators for $C_4 \cdot D_8$

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is there a presentation with two generators and two relators for the group $C_4 \cdot D_8$?
This group is of order 32 and its IdSmallGroup in GAP is [32,15].
Also it has the following presentation with 2 generators and 3 relators:

$\langle x,y \;|\; y^x=y^3, (y^2)^x=y^{-2}, yx^{-1}y=x^3\rangle$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\langle x,y \mid y^x=y^3, yx^{-1}y=x^{-5}\rangle.$$

I found that presentation by trial and error, but minimal presentations are known for $2$-groups of order up to $64$. See

Sag, T. W.; Wamsley, J. W.
 Minimal presentations for groups of order $2^n$, $n \le 6$,
 J. Austral. Math. Soc. 15 (1973), 461–469.

Comment: @ Many thanks. Could you please give a bit explanation how you get this presentation?

Comment: In the reference, $2n$ should be $2^n$.

Comment: @AlirezaAbdollahi Often such presentations are found by brute force search : For a generating set, run through all words up to a certain length to see which are relators, then take combinations of relators and see whether a coset enumeration happens to terminate and prove the result.

Comment: My search didn't really take long. I tried missing out the second relator and found that gave a group of order $96$, which looked promising. Since $x$ and $y$ should both have order $8$, I tried replacing the $x^3$ in the original presentation by $x^{-5}$, knowing that tricks like that often work.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks. Could you please let me know your opinion about the following question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/209438/minimal-number-of-defining-relators-of-a-finite-p-group-on-a-minimal-generatin

Comment: @ahulpke Thanks. Could you please let me know your opinion about the following question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/209438/minimal-number-of-defining-relators-of-a-finite-p-group-on-a-minimal-generatin

Comment: I am not aware of any work on minimal presentations of $2$-groups that goes further than $2^6$, which was done by Wamsley a long time ago. BTW, the groups of order $2^{10}$ are not currently in the GAP library. The total number of such groups is known, but they have not been listed individually.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thanks for the information.

Comment: @ahulpke: Thanks for the information given by email! I will be happy if you could enter them as a comment!