# A discrete presentation for a free prop-$p$-group

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups

Let $n\geq 1$ be an integer and $p$ a prime. Suppose that $\mathcal{F}(n,p)$ is the free prop-p-group of rank $n$.

Question: For each pair $(n,p)$, is it known a discrete free group $\mathfrak{F}$ and an explicitly described subset $\mathfrak{X}$ of $\mathfrak{F}$ such that $\mathcal{F}(n,p)\cong \frac{\mathfrak{F}}{\langle \mathfrak{X} \rangle^\mathfrak{F}}$, where $\langle \mathfrak{X} \rangle^\mathfrak{F}$ is the normal closure of the subgroup generated by $\mathfrak{X}$ in $\mathfrak{F}$?

Certainly such a free group $\mathfrak{F}$ and subset $\mathfrak{X}$ exist. My question is about giving explicitly such a pair $(\mathfrak{F},\mathfrak{X})$. The rank of such free groups $\mathfrak{F}$ must be uncountable as $\mathcal{F}(n,p)$ is uncountable.

Comment: For the question itself, you have the canonical choice (as in any group), the free group over $\mathfrak{F}(n,p)$, with all the length three relations as relators.

Comment: @YCor: Can you write down the presentation for $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in your way?

Comment: I already did: for every group $G$ you consider the free group $F_G=\{e_g:g\in G\}$, the subset $R_G=\{e_{gh}e_h^{-1}e_g^{-1}:g,h\in G\}$, and you get $G=F_G/\langle\langle R_g\rangle\rangle$, where $\langle\langle X\rangle\rangle$ means the normal subgroup generated by $X$.

Comment: @YCor: Is it possible to present the free pro-p-group as a free group quotient "without referring to the free pro-p-group itself"? Or maybe better to say, find a subset $X$ in $R_G$ which is minimal with respect to the inclusion such that $\langle \langle X \rangle \rangle=\langle \langle R_G \rangle \rangle$. Anyway, this may have a more or less trivial answer as the problem is to how define "explicit".

Comment: I'm not very optimistic that we can get anything beyond my suggestion and easy variants. Otherwise it sounds hopelessly hard. Are you trying to compute the cohomology of $F(n,p)$ as a discrete group?

Comment: @YCor: No. I am not trying to compute the cohomology. I am interested in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/209438/minimal-number-of-defining-relators-of-a-finite-p-group-on-a-minimal-generatin It is known that the number $R_G$ defined in the latter link is the minimum number of relations needed to present the finite $p$-group $G$ as a (topological) quotient of the free pro-$p$-group of rank $d_G$ the minimum number of generators of $G$.